# Problema com código em C++

Tags: array, c++, algoritmo, matemática

Estava escrevendo um código e estagnei em algum problema no meio do caminho. Segue abaixo mais detalhes:

---

### Enunciado

> O Afonso está na fila para comprar bilhetes para o concerto da sua
>   banda favorita. O Afonso está no fim da fila, por isso o tempo de
>   espera parece interminável. Para passar o tempo, o Afonso decidiu
>   contar as pessoas que se encontram há sua frente, há exatamente N
>   pessoas. Adicionalmente, o Afonso anotou a altura de cada pessoa, por
>   ordem desde o primeiro da fila até ao último. É sabido que uma pessoa
>   consegue ver a bilheteira se não houver ninguém à sua frente com a
>   mesma altura ou superior. Dada a lista das alturas N pessoas na fila à
>   frente do Afonso, por ordem desde o primeiro da fila até ao último
>   (que se encontra imediatamente à frente do Afonso), consegues contar
>   quantas pessoas conseguem ver a bilheteira?

Dado o número de pessoas **N** na fila e a altura de cada uma *por ordem*, calcular o número de pessoas que consegue ver a bilheteira.

**Input**

Um inteiro N numa linha, o número de pessoas na fila. A linha seguinte tem N inteiros, as alturas das pessoas por ordem de posição na fila, ou seja, o primeiro inteiro é a altura da primeira pessoa na fila.

**Output**

Um inteiro numa linha, correspondente ao número de pessoas que consegue ver a bilheteira, seguida de uma mudança de linha.

**Restrições**

São garantidos os seguintes limites em todos os casos de teste que irão ser colocados ao programa:

- 1 ≤ N ≤ 100          Número de pessoas
- 1 ≤ Ai ≤ 1 000       Altura de cada pessoa

**Exemplo 1**

```
5 
170 153 170 180 175
2
```

Apenas duas pessoas conseguem ver a bilheteira, a primeira pessoa, de altura 170 e a quarta, de altura 180.

**Exemplo 2**

```
7 
10 120 30 135 11 2 186
4
```

### A Dúvida

Numa tentativa de resolver este problema, escrevi o seguinte código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int array[101];

int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        cin >> array[i];
    }
    int sum;

    for(int i = 0; i < x - 1; i++) {
        if(array[i] < array[i + 1]) {
            sum += 1;
        }

    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

E portanto se alguém me pudesse dizer o que está mal, agradecia imenso.
Cumps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Análise

Em uma análise do código, percebe-se que deve ter se atrapalhado um pouco em como comparar as alturas. Olhe o trecho `if(array[i] < array[i + 1])`. Nota-se sua tentativa de ver qual a maior altura. Perfeito!

*Mas qual é o problema, jovem? Para funcional para mim...*

**Veja bem**: se pessoa **A** tem `21` de altura e **B** que está atrás tem `19` de altura, usando a lógica do exercício, **B** não enxerga a bilheteria. OK.

**Repare que** atrás de **B**, está **C**. Assim, a próxima comparação é, segundo o trecho de código referenciado acima, de **B** com **C**. Considere que **C** tenha `20` de altura. Como **C** é mais alto que **B**, concluímos **C** enxerga a bilheteria!...

*... ou será que não?*

**Não!** Não se esqueça de que **A ainda é mais alto que C** e bloqueia a visão dele. Portanto, deveria-se comparar C com A e não com B como está no código.

**Em resumo:** nesta situação, sempre deve-se comparar com a última altura mais alta observada andando do começo da fila até o final. Assim, faz falta de uma variável extra que vai armazenar - e atualizar conforme necessário - a altura mais alta de comparação!

### O Código

Fiz apenas as modificações necessárias para torná-lo funcional e tomei a liberdade de dar uns espaçamentos para termos uma melhor visualização do código. Veja:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int x, i, sum, height, array[100]; // Rearranjado tudo em um local

    cin >> x;

    for(i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        cin >> array[i];
    }

    height = array[0]; // Define uma altura de comparação (primeiro da fila)
    sum    = 1;        // A primeira pessoa sempre vai ver a bilheteria

    for(i = 1; i < x; i++) { // i=1 pois começa comparando ao 2o da fila

        if(array[i] > height) {
            sum   += 1;        
            height = array[i]; // array[i] é o mais alto agora p/ comparação
        }

    }

    cout << sum << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

### Recomendações

- Tentar manter o código organizado. Por exemplo, usar de espaçamentos;
- Sempre optar por declarar suas variáveis no começo da função. Deixa tudo mais claro;

**NOTA:** Você chegou *bem perto* de solucionar. Deve estar apenas com a cabeça quente! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seu código consegue definir bem um valor para para o tamanho da fila e as alturas das pessoas que estão nela. No meu ver, o que apenas falta para resolver bem o problema é aplicar as restrições do enunciado no código e talvez melhorar a solução melhor para encontrar a quantidade de pessoas que pode ver a fila.
Para colocar as restrições, utilizarei a estrutura do while. Agora, para encontrar a quantidade irei utilizar a seguinte lógica. A primeira pessoa sempre vai ver a bilheteria e no começo da fila será considerada a maior, então sum = 1 e maior = array[0]. Depois disso, vamos comparando as pessoas atrás para descobrir quem a maior depois da primeira, sempre quando descobrirmos vamos atualizar o valor de maior e somar um valor ao sum. Segue abaixo o código que utilizei para resolver esse problema.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int array[101];

int main()
{
int x;
//testando restrição de pessoas na fila
do{
    cout<<"Digite a quantidade de pessoas na fila ";
    cin >> x;
}while(x < 1 || x > 100);

//obtendo as alturas
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    //testando restrição de altura
    do{
        cout<<"Digite as alturas: ";
        cin >> array[i];
    }while(array[i] < 1 || array[i] > 1000);
}

int sum = 1;
int maior = array[0];

//encontrar a maior altura
for(int i = 0; i < x - 1; i++) {

    if(array[i +1] > array[i] && array[i + 1] > maior) {
        sum += 1;
        maior = array[i +1];
    }

}
cout <<"A quantidade de pessoas que podem ver a bilheteria é: "<< sum << endl;
return 0;
```

}